# how to serve static files with nodejs in multiple routing

Tags: node.js, express, ejs

I am trying to make a website of my small bussiness of cables and wires
using nodejs express (ejs)

files are like:

app.js

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var favicon = require('serve-favicon');
var logger = require('morgan');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

/* routes variables*/

var routes = require('./routes/index');
var cableWires = require('./routes/cableWires');

var app = express();

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.engine('html', require('ejs').renderFile);
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');


app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(require('less-middleware')(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
app.use(express.static('public'));
app.use(express.static('public/stylesheets'));
app.use(express.static('public/images'));
app.use(express.static('public/javascripts'));


/* routes */
app.use('/', routes);   // index page
app.use('/cableWires', cableWires);   //cables and wires

app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  var err = new Error('Not Found');
  err.status = 404;
  next(err);
});

// error handlers

// development error handler
// will print stacktrace
if (app.get('env') === 'development') {
  app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
    res.status(err.status || 500);
    res.render('error', {
      message: err.message,
      error: err
    });
  });
}

// production error handler
// no stacktraces leaked to user
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  res.status(err.status || 500);
  res.render('error', {
    message: err.message,
    error: {}
  });
});


module.exports = app;
```

In routes/cablesWires.js

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  res.render('products_cableWires', { title: 'Umesh Electricals' });


});

router.get('/submersible_cables', function(req, res, next) {
  res.render('submersible-cables', { title: 'Umesh Electricals' });
});


router.get('/house_wires', function(req, res, next) {
  res.render('house-wires', { title: 'Umesh Electricals' });
});

module.exports = router;
```

When I go to **cableWires** page, everything is fine,
but when I go to **house_wires** page or **submersible_cables** page, it loads the content of ejs file but fails to load static files (css, javascript and images)

What could be the possible mistake am I doing

Answer (score 0):

Its seems that when you make request to any route then it try to fetch that file from that URL path i.e - when you call /route1 then it will call the static file from relative path..so you have to change it to absolute path..
so change the static path and include "/" before static path

```
app.use(express.static('public')); app.use(express.static('/public/stylesheets')); app.use(express.static('/public/images')); app.use(express.static('/public/javascript
```

Let us know if its help

Comment: your method rather than putting a absolute path, is actually changing the path where server would search for static files